# Using seltzer to help a marinade

Tags: food-science, marinade

I saw the host on a cooking show claim that using seltzer in a marinade will help the flavors better penetrate meat via the carbonation. Is there any truth to this, and how would it actually work? e.g. would the bubbles carry bits of flavor material, or somehow open "pores" in the meat...?

Comment: Interesting claim; I know that seltzer is used to *aerate* certain sauces and batters and thus *lighten* them, but I don't think I've ever heard of it being used to improve a marinade. Google turned up one or two "explanations" of this process but they sound a little like pseudoscience. Mind my asking which TV chef said this?

Comment: I believe it was "Star Kitchen" on TVB.

Comment: Susur Lee did a sweet and sour pork marinated with Sprite at his  eponymous restaurant in Toronto and it was super tender and delicious.  No idea of the food science behind it though.

Comment: I make [chicken adobo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobo) pretty regularly, and my friend's Filipino mom introduced me to her "secret" ingredient, a half can of Sprite.  The one time I didn't have any on hand, I adjusted for the sugar content, and it was good, but the final product wasn't the same.  Like Allison, I'm not sure what's happening, just adding to the discussion :)

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly doubt that the bubbles themselves would have any mechanical effect on flavor.  However, seltzer or soda water has a acidic pH, usually between tomato and orange juice. This could account for any tenderizing action. The addition of salts to some seltzers might also account for apparent changes in flavor.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a recipe that contains seltzer , but I would imagine that it is the same reaction that MSG has in Asian cooking, where restaurants can use cheap cuts and tenderizes the meat before cooking. Most MSG is banned in restaurants now.
I myself have used coca cola in marinades in meats like ribs and pork belly as the acids does the same thing to the meat tendons as well as giving sweetness to the meat.

Comment: Coca Cola is really acidic in addition to being sweet, so I'd say any tenderization that happens is probably because of that rather than the bubbles (which, come to think of it, is probably what's happening with the seltzer, which is also acidic).

Comment: MMMM.... this reminds me of root beer in a slow cooker with pork. yummey.

Comment: In other words, it's basically an expensive an inefficient version of vinegar?  (Coca Cola is obviously flavourful as @bikeboy says but plain seltzer water is just going to be very weak carbonic acid).

Comment: @aaronut I certainly can't think of anything else it would be bringing to the party.

Comment: I suppose the way to test this would be to try a recipe with flat coke (and some with fresh, carbonated coke as a control) and see if the flat coke produces the same result.

Comment: what is "most" MSG? MSG is MSG, regardless of the brand. And MSG does not have a tenderizing effect: it is added for flavor.

Answer (score 0):

I use sparkling waters when I brine. It looks like it has a PH level of between 3 and 4 so it is acidic. I still add salt (which bubbles when added) and lemon juice for added acid.

One thing that may be a contributing factor is those bubbles. Well not the bubbles themselves but the escaping gas.

If the container being used is sealed you are increasing the pressure inside of that container which should assist in penetration.

I use ziplock bags so the aid can't be all that much but the results are always a very juicy piece of meat. Or fish as I am doing right now (a good portion of dill is sitting in there too).

Comment: This is very theoretical. The pressure is negligible, and you'll have   hard time finding a kitchen container (other than a pressure cooker) that can hold any effective pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Was in Missoula Montana at local hospital and my spouse got talking with local Native American Indian about hunting and cooking. She said *after* cooking wild turkey she submerged *in* ginger ale/ seltzer mix  for 3 days and it makes meat very tender & soft......especially legs of wild turkey which there is no other way to soften. (According to her)  ......she had to be at least 70yrs and had no teeth....so I image the meat did become soft as that would be the only way she could eat it.